# Advice for building a Brick Rocket Stove

Tags: construction

After watching video I'm really interested in building something similar. I see that most bricks have holes in them. I'm wondering whether you can use some sort of steel rods that you taper in these holes so that there is no chance of the bricks moving.

Also what sort of oil can you treat the red bricks with the make them look pretty. Obviously, I want to cook from this makeshift oven but if possible I also want to make it look pretty. I'm just concerned that some treatments may not like to be put on hot bricks.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Adfq5E5d0-8

Comment: I hope this does not qualify as a hobby project. According to the FAQ they are off topic.

Comment: If this is going to be a permanent installation, I'd mortar the bricks instead of "pinning them".  As for aesthetics, you may want to consider using glazed bricks instead of trying to apply some sort of coating on your own.

Comment: I think you'll find that those bricks with holes in them aren't fire bricks.